# \begin{filecontents}{tabelle.tex} will not overwrite existing file

Tags: filecontents

The old environment (before 10/2019)

```latex
 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents}{tabelle.tex}
  ... some text ...
 \end{filecontents}`
```

will overwrite an existing file `tabelle.tex`.

After my update yesterday in debian sid, it does not work any more.

I removed the `\usepackage{filecontents}` because the functionality should now be inside the LaTeX kernel.

But `filecontents` will not overwrite my file (with respective message in log):

```
LaTeX Warning: File 'tabelle.tex' already exists on the system.
               Not generating it from this source.
```

Trying to force overwrite with 
`\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{tabelle.tex}` leads to error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Trying to overwrite 'kivitendo-print7y2OSd.tex'.
```

So it looks like it tries to overwrite the encompassing file.

Is this a bug or am I missing a point?

Edited 09.11.2019:

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{addfile.tex}
    \centering{Hello World!}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    Just a test.
\end{document}
```

Apparantly, the `\usepackage{etex}` causes the error.
The latex code is used by the web application kivitendo.
Within my short test, I see no drawback to eliminate the package 'etex'.
After that, for me it's working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you please provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the new kernel? We've seen a lot of people where the packages were updated but not the kernel. The kernel version is listed at the top of the log

Comment: @daleif The message `Trying to overwrite ...` was introduced in the new kernel when trying to write on `\jobname.tex`, so it should be the new version. OP probably has some code writing on `\jobname.tex`, for some reason. Impossible to tell without an example...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I like that the message seems to occur only in case `\jobname.tex` exists. (This is not necessarily the case when calling latex with the `-jobname=...`-option. ;-)  )

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, the overwrite-check code is only executed if the target file exists, so if `\jobname.tex` does not exist. it should be safe to write on it. That's one of the problems we discussed when writing this implementation. There's no reliable way to test “am I trying to write on the current source?”, so the approach we agreed on was to test for  `\jobname.tex`, which will be correct _most_ of the time. Everywhere else, user's discretion is advised.

Comment: In a simple example I tried `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{notatabelle.tex}` resulted in ```LaTeX Warning: Writing or overwriting file `./notatabelle.tex'.``` and a correctly overwritten file `notatabelle.tex`. Can you show a full example document (and explain how you compile that document) that reproduces this weird behaviour?

Comment: Ulrike opened an issue at the `etex` bugtracker: https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/issues/23, there is also some discussion about this in chat starting from https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52492694#52492694

Answer (score 10):

The main difference is the old definition of `\ch@ck` that is re-instated by etex.sty

The error could be avoided by

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\zzz\ch@ck
\usepackage{etex}
\let\ch@ck\zzz
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{addfile.tex}
    \centering{Hello World!}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    Just a test.
\end{document}
```

but a much better fix would be to simply not use `etex.sty` it shouldn't be used in any documents written after 2015, and no documents written before 2015 can be using `\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]`

Ulrike has opened an issue on `etex.sty` bug tracker, we could perhaps adjust the definition of `\ch@ck` in the package, as above, but any change may affect compatibility with other packages assuming the original definitions, and compatibility with such packages is the only reason for `etex.sty` these days, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

As `filecontents` of LaTeX 2ε 2019‑10‑01 Patch level 1 uses `\ifeof` for checking the existence of the file in question, you can outmanoeuvre the file-existence-check by temporarily refefining `\ifeof` to deliver `\iftrue` after removing the token which denotes the `\ifeof`-read-handle:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2019-10-01 Patch level 1]
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
\global\let\savedifeof=\ifeof
\def\ifeof#1{\global\let\ifeof=\savedifeof\iftrue}%
\begin{filecontents}{tabelle.tex}
... some text ...
\end{filecontents}
\endgroup

\begin{document}
Bla
\end{document}
```

I showed this just for the sake of having fun while playing around with the latest novelties.

I cannot recommend this for serious work.

Instead I strongly recommend tracking the cause of the erroneous behavior.

For doing this, a compilable complete minimal example is needed by means of which the erroneous behavior can be reproduced.
`\listfiles` and the look of the .log-file might be of interest, too, so one can find out what package-versions etc are in use.

Comment: Formatting of comments (code, linebreaks) as mentioned in help does not work, so I will edit my original quesiton.